# Replacement for "man" in "Man is the only animal that can make use of fire"

Tags: word-choice

> **Man** is the only animal that can make use of fire.        (0)

I want to replace "man" with other word.

> Human beings are the only animal that can make use of fire.  (1)
>
> The human race is the only animal that can make use of fire. (2)
>
> Human kind is the only animal that can make use of fire.     (3)

Are they grammatically correct? Are their meanings the same as (0)'s?

Comment: the third one: "Human kind" should be replaced with "The mankind"

Comment: @sotondolphin I think that he meant 'humankind' which is actually a word. I just searched it up myself.

Comment: @sotondolphin No, most of such words with 'man' are now getting neutral with 'human/person'. Another example: businessperson and not 'man'.

Comment: Better choice if I were to write: *"Humans are the only ones who can make use of fire"* Why separate 'animals' for this **universal truth?**

Answer (score 1):

> Human beings are the only animal that can make use of fire. (1)

Changing 'animal' to 'animals' would make it a bit tidier as you'd have two plurals.  You could also say "Humans are the only animals that can make use of fire."

> The human race is the only animal that can make use of fire. (2)

Looks a bit odd, as the human race isn't something you'd normally refer to as an animal, but still understandable.

> Human kind is the only animal that can make use of fire. (3)

Humankind is a single word, but otherwise this looks OK.

All of these mean the same as your original sentence, but (1) is the one I would use myself.

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE NOTE that the statement is false.  There are animals other than humans that make use of fire, including some birds.

But anyway:

Human beings is plural, so your first form needs to be

> Human beings are the only animals that can make use of fire.

The human race is a poorly defined collective and not an animal, so the second form is probably best as

> Of all the animals, only the human race can make use of fire.

and finally in the third form humankind is a single word and plural.

> Humankind are the only animals that can make use of fire.

But the statement is false in every case.